# General solution of $y'' + \frac{\sin x}{1 + \cos x}y' + \frac{1}{1 + \cos x}y =0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was hoping to get some help with this question.

How do you find the general solution of 
$$
y'' + \frac{\sin x}{1 + \cos x}y' + \frac{1}{1 + \cos x}y =0.
$$
 I'm not used to dealing with complex trig functions. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: When you say complex, do you mean as in complex variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to recgonize that 
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\right) = \dfrac1{1+\cos(x)}$$
We hence, get the equation as $$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right) + \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{y \sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\right) = 0 \implies \dfrac{dy}{dx} + \dfrac{y \sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)} = \text{constant}$$
I trust you can take it from here.

Comment: @RickyRozay Yes. $$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{y \sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\right) = \dfrac{y' \sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)} + \dfrac{y}{1+\cos(x)}$$